# Как открыть определенную папку в проводнике kotlin?

Tags: kotlin

Мне бы хотелось открыть определенную папку в проводнике через мою программу на котлине. Эквивалент кода на питоне будет таким:

```py
import os
path = "C:/Users"
path = os.path.realpath(path)
os.startfile(path)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Вариант с использованием стандартного `java.awt.Desktop`.

```
import java.awt.Desktop
import java.io.File

fun main(args : Array<String>) {
    val file = File("c:\\")
    if (Desktop.isDesktopSupported()) {
        val desktop = Desktop.getDesktop()
        if (desktop.isSupported(Desktop.Action.OPEN)) {
            desktop.open(file)
        }
    }
}
```

Теоретически будет работать на всех платформах, что поддерживают действие `OPEN` и `Desktop`.

Answer (score 0):

```kotlin
Runtime.getRuntime().exec("cmd /c start C:\")
```